# What exactly is controlling single HTTP requests speed?

Tags: performance, vps, http

As you may know using multiple HTTP threads when downloading a file from a server can significantly increase your download speeds if not max it out.
What is control of determine the throughput of every request? 
I have three possibilities: the client, the server and the ISP. 
Example: I'm currently at college using its 100Mbit connection (I really have this kind of BW confirmed by the speedtest.net. If I download from my VPS (nginx) with a single HTTP request the speed is stuck at 800-900KB/s, however if I use 4 or more threads I can almost max it out to about 9MB/s (probably limit of the VPS connection).
So why isn't the BW given all together if it's there available to use from both ends?

Comment: Probably bandwidth delay product.

Answer (score 1):

> I have three possibilities: the client, the server and the ISP.

That are N possibilities. THe last one "the ISP" is really:

- The server ISP
- THe client ISP
- ANYONE IN BETWEEN

There also is some loss in large latency scenarios mostly.

But assuming you have a 100mbit link because both ends have more bandiwdth is possibly ignoring items like the bandwidth of in between links. Unless you are VERY local, the traffic will cross multiple networks.

Comment: Not to mention he said he's on a college campus. Almost all colleges implement rate-limiting to some degree.

Comment: And likely do not have a HUUUUGH bandiwdth. Or, it may LOOK big, but it is not during prime time when everyone is utilizing it ;)

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/46482/tech-lead-dba-postgres-oracle-tomtom?a=UGKxPxWU :)  Found that for you...I'll delete it but you aren't in chat to tell you about the funny.

Answer (score 0):

There are plently ways of capping/limiting bandwidth on a per-flow basis. Without more information I cannot say which one is being used.